# Posting a whole div content from a view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

`<div>` below is in a .cshtml file. It's going to be saved to database in the controller. And then it'll be displayed as html. See the `contenteditable` attributes of the span elements. Where it says "CLICK TO CHANGE", user will click and put sth, and then will post it. `<div>` elements are not allowed to have name attribute either. How can I send the whole content into the database as-is?

```
<form id="newadform" action="/ad/new" method="post">
   <div>
       <font color="#000000" face="Times New Roman" size="3">
       <p align="center" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 8pt;">
       <img width="730" height="380" src="https://abc.blob.core.windows.net/help/bbca-100.png"></p></font>
       <p><b><span>&nbsp;</span></b></p>
       <p><span contenteditable="true" onkeypress="return(this.innerText.length <= 80)" >CLICK TO CHANGE</span></p>
       <font color="#000000" face="Times New Roman" size="3"></font>
       <p style="background: white; margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt; line-height: normal; vertical-align: baseline; mso-outline-level: 2;">
       <span lang="TR" style='color: rgb(217, 72, 69); font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 16.5pt; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-fareast-language: TR;'>&nbsp;</span>
       </p>
       <p><span lang="TR" >Definition</span></p>
       <p><span lang="TR" style='color: rgb(217, 72, 69); font-family: "Arial","sans-serif"; font-size: 16.5pt; mso-fareast-font-family: "Times New Roman"; mso-fareast-language: TR;'>&nbsp;</span></p>
   </div>
</form>
```

EDIT:

```
 public ActionResult New(string id, string pid, AdDetail model)
 {
     Operation operation = new Operation(User.Token, 2);
     AdOperation omodel = GetModel(new AdOperation(), model);
     UpdateAd ohelper = operation.SaveAd(omodel);
     return Redirect("/ad/detail/" + ohelper.Model.AdId);
 }
```

AdDetail class(Model):

```
 public class AdDetail: BaseVRqH
 {
    public string txt1 { get; set; }
    public string txt2 { get; set; }
    public string AdCode{ get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Please just concentrate to saving it to the database.

Comment: you can just save your div html as it is in database..

Comment: just try below answer...

Comment: Been waiting you rewrite your answer based on the edit I made.

Comment: @Jude see my edit...  Hope it will help...

Comment: @Jude...just read comments and updated answer... comment if problem persists....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("form").submit(function{
   $.ajax({
        url: "/ControllerName/SaveHtml",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { divhtml:$("#div1").html() },
        success: function (data) {}
        });
});

   [HttpPost] 
   [ValidateInput(false)]  <----------this is necessary to disable inbuilt MVC Security(in order to save html tags)
   public JsonResult SaveHtml(string divhtml)
    {
        // Save html to database
        return Json(new{ result="true" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Just give your `div` id `div1`

Comment: Why do we need to diable MVC in built security? what about `[AllowHtml]` ?

Comment: @RJK...[AllowHtml] will work on model property but here he is not using any html helper...

Comment: @Exception OK. I can give it a try. I edited the question. Added the Action Method. Normally when we post sth like <input type="text" name="txt1"/> we include the name of the element in the model class as a property. How can I do it in this way?

Comment: @Exception I guess he is using model in his view. But he did't posted entire code of view here. `AdDetail model`

Comment: @RJK That's what it is

Comment: @Exception Stuck with contentType="application/html". Returns null. changed it to contentType="application/json". Giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at below example code:

Declare once more property in your model like blow and Hidden field in your view.

In Your view just add the `Jquery Submit event`. when `click on form submit`. Just assign the html text to that property. Like Below.

**Model:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string RequestText { get; set; }  // You will get this html in this property
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            RequestText = "<strong>Hello World</strong>";
        };
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // Save operations Goes Here
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.RequestText) // Remove or Comment this line

    <input type="hidden" name="RequestText" id="RequestText">

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}

<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  //if you want to bind the html to this then assign the requesttext property value here... Like below...

  $('#divHtml').html('@model.RequestText'); // properly you can assign your model here

  $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
     $('RequestText').val($('#divHtml').html());
     return true;
  });
 });

</script>
```

Reference from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810067/allowhtml-not-working-for-asp-net-mvc-3-site/8810221#8810221) - [Darin Dimitrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov)

I Just did `Copy Cat work Here` to solve your problem. :)